# Populating one field in a form using the result from a select list in the same form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to populate one field in a form based on the option the user chooses from a select (dropdown) list, in real time. If the user checks the Beginners radio button, the Class Time field is populated with 20:00 and disabled. For any other class, the user needs to set the Class Time, which is what I want to achieve.

I can get this to work using html/java script when I use radio buttons, but I want to use a select list instead, but I am unsure how to do this as I am beginner with java script.

Here is my code:

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('class');
var classtime = document.getElementById('classtime');

for(radio in radios) {
    radios[radio].onclick = function() {
      if (this.value === 'Beginners') {
          classtime.value = '20:00';
          classtime.disabled = true;
       } else {
          classtime.value = '';
          classtime.disabled = false;
       }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerx">

  <h4>Our Classes</h4>

  <p>Please select a class</p>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="begclass" name="class" value="Beginners" required>
      <label for="begclass">Beginners</label>
      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="impclass" name="class" value="Improvers" required>
      <label for="impclass">Improvers</label>
      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="intclass" name="class" value="Intermediate" required>
      <label for="intclass">Intermediate</label>
      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="advclass" name="class" value="Advanced" required>
      <label for="advclass">Advanced</label>
      <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __first" style="z-index: 0">
  <label for="classtime"><p>Please select class time</p></label><br>
  <input name="classtime" type="time" id="classtime" max="20:00:00" min="09:00:00" step="900" tabindex="0" title="Class Time"/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code replaces radio with a select. Besides changing the variable names, the only real change is changing `onclick` to `onchange`.

```
var selects = document.getElementsByName('class');
var classtime = document.getElementById('classtime');

for(select in selects) {
    select.onchange = function() {
      if (this.value === 'Beginners') {
          classtime.value = '20:00';
          classtime.disabled = true;
       } else {
          classtime.value = '';
          classtime.disabled = false;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `oninput` event instead: 
I also used a `for of` loop instead for simplicity

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('class');
var classtime = document.getElementById('classtime');

for (const radio of radios) {
  radio.addEventListener("input", e => {
    if (e.target.value === 'Beginners') {
      classtime.value = '20:00';
      classtime.disabled = true;
    } else {
      classtime.value = '';
      classtime.disabled = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="containerx">

  <h4>Our Classes</h4>

  <p>Please select a class</p>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="begclass" name="class" value="Beginners" required>
      <label for="begclass">Beginners</label>
      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="impclass" name="class" value="Improvers" required>
      <label for="impclass">Improvers</label>
      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="intclass" name="class" value="Intermediate" required>
      <label for="intclass">Intermediate</label>
      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="advclass" name="class" value="Advanced" required>
      <label for="advclass">Advanced</label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __first" style="z-index: 0">
  <label for="classtime">
    <p>Please select class time</p>
  </label><br>
  <input name="classtime" type="time" id="classtime" max="20:00:00" min="09:00:00" step="900" tabindex="0" title="Class Time" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using checkbox, I use dropdown select. When the select is change and get the value. and then do the logic.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('class');

select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  var classtime = document.getElementById('classtime');
  if (e.target.value === 'beginners') {
    classtime.value = '20:00:00';
    classtime.disabled = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="containerx">

  <h4>Our Classes</h4>
  <select id="class">
    <option>Select Class</option>
    <option value="beginners">Beginners</option>
    <option value="improvers">Improvers</option>
    <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
    <option value="advance">Advance</option>
  </select>

</div>
<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-input __first" style="z-index: 0">
  <label for="classtime"><p>Please select class time</p></label><br>
  <input name="classtime" type="time" id="classtime" max="20:00:00" min="09:00:00" step="900" tabindex="0" title="Class Time" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bihasry. The Select list is what I want to use. But the problem with this solution is that if the user has mistakenly selected Beginners, this code does not allow them to then select the class they meant to select.

Comment: Yeap, I forgot to put handler to set it to enabled it again. Thanks